# Python Logging troubles with simple example

Tags: python, logging

I tried a simple example based on official Logging Cookbook but the result is unexpected:

```
LOG_PATH = 'logs'

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Creates 2 Handlers to split log levels
info_fh = logging.FileHandler(path.join(LOG_PATH, 'info_level.log'))
info_fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
err_fh = logging.FileHandler(path.join(LOG_PATH, 'err_level.log'))
err_fh.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

# Create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
info_fh.setFormatter(formatter)
err_fh.setFormatter(formatter)

# add the handlers to logger
logger.addHandler(info_fh)
logger.addHandler(err_fh)
```

Then I write in a console:

```
In [2]: logger.info("hello")
In [3]: logger.error("bad")
```

Later:

```
cat logs/err_level.log
>>> 2017-02-27 13:16:40,328 - jive - ERROR - bad

cat logs/info_level.log
>>> 2017-02-27 13:16:40,328 - jive - ERROR - bad
```

I don't understand why the info_level.log file does NOT contain the "hello" log record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That probably means that your `logger`'s own level is higher than `logging.INFO` (20). This value is inherited from parent logger:

```
>>> logger.level  
0  # that means it is not set
>>> logging.NOTSET
0
>>> logger.getEffectiveLevel()
30  # value of parent because not set
>>> logger.parent.level       
30
>>> logging.INFO
20  # < logger.getEffectiveLevel()  -> not picked up
```

Set logger's level manually:

```
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> logger.getEffectiveLevel()
10
```

Now the `info` logs will be picked up. From the `Logger.getEffectiveLevel` [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.getEffectiveLevel):

> Indicates the effective level for this logger. If a value other than NOTSET has been set using setLevel(), it is returned. Otherwise, the hierarchy is traversed towards the root until a value other than NOTSET is found, and that value is returned

Elsewhere:

> Note that the root logger is created with level WARNING.

Comment: Thanks for the perfect explanation.